# Apache folder redirects also lose www

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Let's say I have the domain "example.com" which works both with and without the "www." prefix.

And let's say I have a folder thereon called "extra".

When someone visits www.example.com/extra I would expect Apache to redirect them to www.example.com/extra/. But no! Instead, they're sent to example.com/extra/. Losing the www. prefix means that (a) a new session is generated, and the user is signed out, and (b) the security certificate becomes invalid.

I'm using Apache on a shared hosting platform (hsphere).

.htaccess file is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Web application failed to start properly"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: could you show your configuration? are there any redirect rules?

Comment: No redirect rules, only rewrites. I've added the .htaccess file above.

Comment: The rules you posted don't perform any redirection.  Can you post your configs? At least the virtualhost definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because of a [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) directive in your Apache httpd configuration. Just set it to `UseCanonical off` or delete the directive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try playing with that and see what happens.